# npm install mdbreact ERR

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, npm, mern, mdbreact

I need some help with a project MERN stack,
I'm having an error downloading a library "mdbreact" using [npm i mdbreact]
npm -v :8.3.1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prFse.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rFoc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by downloading an old version.

```
npm i mdbreact@4.8.7
```

link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdbreact

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean your cache using this command `npm  cache clear --force`  Then try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it didn't work the download starts and stops.